# How can I create a list of sums of random numbers in Python?

Tags: python, random

Can I write a for loop to get a series of sums of random numbers? I'm new with it. I have no clue.

Comment: sum *one* random number? :) | also, can you tell us why do you want to do this?

Comment: Do you know how to generate random numbers, do you know how to add numbers and do you know how to write a for loop? If you can do each of these, then it should be trivial to do.

Comment: For most practical uses, summing 10 random numbers is the same as taking a single random number and multiplying it by 10.

Comment: @Wallacoloo: That depends highly on the distribution of the numbers. The sum of 10 uniformly distributed random numbers is _not_ uniformly distributed. In fact, by the [central limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) it approaches a normal distribution. On the other hand, a single uniformly distributed random number multiplied by 10 will still have a uniform distribution.

Comment: What kind of random numbers? What's this for? And what part are you having trouble with?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this. The most compact one, by using numpy, would be "cumsum(rand(100))". If this question gets re-opened, I'm going to cover other methods, too.

Answer (score 3):

```
import random
sum(random.random() for i in range(how_many_random_numbers_do_you_want))
```

Comment: This is not the answer a beginner is looking for . Seriously . Beginners don't need one-liners .

Answer (score 3):

oh for goodness sake.  the other answers here are trying too hard to be cool.

if you are new to this:

```
from random import random
total = 0
for i in range(10):
    total = total + random()
print total
```

[edit: changed `sum` to `total`]

Comment: Even for beginners, rebinding the builtin name `sum` is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

by using numpy you can generate this kind of random numbers quickly:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.sum(random.rand(100,10000),axis=0)
```

or

```
b = np.sum(random.rand(10000) for i in xrange(100)) # this one will use less memory
```

the program will create 10000 random numbers, and every number is the sum of 100 uniformly distributed random numbers.

and you can get the mean & var of the random numbers:

```
In [69]: np.mean(a)
Out[69]: 49.9569087164707

In [70]: np.var(a)
Out[70]: 8.2763465318604865
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
sum(map(lambda _: random.randint(0, 255), range(10)))
```

However, I don't see the point of this. The sum of 10 random numbers is not "more random" than a single random number.

Comment: It's "less" random (not uniformly distributed anymore)

Answer (score 0):

The number won't be more random if you add more random numbers together.
You get the same result when just multiplying a random number with the number of random values you want to add.

```
from random import random
random() * 5
```